# best solution for mocking chained calls in Java

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following code:

```
handler = NodeHandler.getINodeHandler(localZone).getITspPlatformHandler().getITspProcessorManagementHandler();
```

I mocked this out this way:

```
mockStatic(NodeHandler.class);
INodeHandler iNodeHandler = mock(INodeHandler.class,Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
when(NodeHandler.getINodeHandler(localZone)).thenReturn(iNodeHandler);
ITspProcessorManagementHandler iTspProcessorManagementHandler =mock(ITspProcessorManagementHandler.class,Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
when(iNodeHandler.getITspPlatformHandler().getITspProcessorManagementHandler()).thenReturn(iTspProcessorManagementHandler);
```

After a few row of code an another chained method call comes:

```
ITspTrafficProcessor processor = NodeHandler.getINodeHandler(localZone, localUI).getITspPlatformHandler().getITspProcessorManagementHandler()
                .getITspProcessorHandler(procs[i]).getITspTrafficProcessorHandler(0).getAttributes();
```

And i mocked this out this way:

```
when(NodeHandler.getINodeHandler(localZone,UI.CORBA)).thenReturn(iNodeHandler);
when(iNodeHandler.getITspPlatformHandler().getITspProcessorManagementHandler()(+1+).getITspProcessorHandler(anyString())
            .getITspTrafficProcessorHandler(anyInt()).getAttributes()).thenReturn(null);
```

So my question is that, i can not find a better solution than this, because the problem is if i tell the mockito to return null to the handler instead of iTspProcessorManagementHandler then i get a nullpointer exception at (+1+), but if i do the following changes to my code:

```
INodeHandler iNodeHandler = mock(INodeHandler.class,Mockito.RETURNS_MOCKS);
```

Than mockito mocks out every method call, and my when-thenReturn statements does not returns what i want for example null. So any advice to do a better solution????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messy mocking like that is an indication that you could improve abstraction. I'd consider encapsulating that particular logic in a helper interface/class, or to inject the expected type returned by the "trainwreck" to the method/class.

Comment: I forgot to write that i work on a legacy code.(or do you think for the test code?)

Comment: Working with legacy code can be a pain. But legacy code can also be refactored. Cases like this is a chance to improve the code quality, step by step. 

Anyway, if you really need to mock trainwrecks like this, I believe you need every method call in the chain to return a mock that you can set up. So you need a `when` and a `thenReturn` for each of the invocations.